# Civilization 5: DLC Civs unavailable despite owning DLCs?

Tags: civilization-5

So I was playing playing Civ 5 with my friend, and we were setting up a new game. I chose a civilization from the Brave New World expansion, which he owns, but on his screen, it said unavailable leader, and it wouldn't allow him to hit "ready."

The strange thing about this is that he owns Brave New World (as well as other DLCs) and we've played using DLC civs before. Even in singleplayer, when he starts a game, he is only able to select civs from the base game. In game, he has access to all the mechanics added by BNW (and G&K). He tried restarting civ, and steam, and his computer.

What could be causing this, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Has he tried running the repair tool to check if any files have gone missing/broken?

Comment: @Erik What exactly do you mean by repair tool? Can't find it in a google sesarch.

Comment: I think he meant "**[Verify integrity of game files](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335)**". Also, is the DLC installed? It should be installed by default, but it's possible your friend uninstalled it by accident.

Comment: @Nolonar It was definitely installed, considering some aspects of the DLC were there. And we tried that already, so no go on that.

Comment: Check that Brave New World is enabled both in the Steam client and within the game. It's possible to disable the DLC while still having it installed. You should also make sure to disable any mods you have installed.

Comment: @RossRidge As said, most aspects of the DLC are in the game, just not the new civilizations, so it seems unlikely that it is disabled. That said, we did check that it is enabled, and there are also no mods enabled or installed.